# How can i assign openFileDialog1.FileNames to FileInfo[]?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
FileInfo[] fi = this.openFileDialog1.FileNames.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToArray();
```

Select not exist after FileNames
FileNames dosen't have the property Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add namespace for [`Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

```
using System.Linq;
```